# PHP/ExtJS date format strings in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to format C# `DateTime` objects as a string according to date format strings that are provided in PHP/ExtJS format (e.g. `m/d/Y g:iA`), but Microsoft uses a different format. [I have found code for a converter for dateformat strings here](https://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-67804.html), but it isn't complete.

Especially, it is lacking the formatters "N", "W" and "o" which I am actively using; but since formats can be changed by the user, I would want to support any format they could find in the PHP docs.

I tried to find the appropriate [Microsoft Custom Date Format Specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), but without luck. They seem to be missing completely.

So a solution would be any of the following:

- It seems as if PHP and ExtJS have copied from the same de-facto standard here, so possibly Microsoft does provide a (well hidden/undocumented) function I didn't find that would allow us to format dates according to this de-facto standard format specifier?
- Are there Microsoft format specifiers available which are not documented in that link I found, which would output the ISO day number, ISO week number, and ISO week number year in the appropriate place of the result string?
- If not, is there a way to add Custom Date Format Specifiers to the DateTime object, so that I could add these missing formats by myself?

Comment: I don't believe the normal `DateTime` facilities handle ISO-week-year or ISO-week-of-week-year at all. (Not sure about ISO day number - I haven't come across that.) You can't add your own date format specifiers. I don't know of any "de-facto standard" being used here - it doesn't look like it's the Unicode standard format (and neither is the MS format). In other words, I think you're facing an uphill task here - I would personally suggest trying to avoid it entirely... if you're writing a C# codebase, can you just use the regular .NET format strings, and manually convert any current formats?

Comment: @JonSkeet I am writing a C# backend with an ExtJS frontend, so I already use ExtJS formats more often than Microsoft formats. Our app has calendaring integrated, so date formats are ubiquituous. Until today, I came along well with formatting in the frontend only (the backend only formatted dates to the ISO standard for transmission), but now I have to generate PDFs of the frontend content in the backend. I doubt it's pretty to format all dates into all the different formats on the client and submit that mess to the backend for PDF rendering.

Comment: Hmm. I suspect that having the rendering logic in both places *is* going to cause problems, almost whatever you do. Without knowing more about the app (more detail than would be suitable here) it's hard to know what to recommend - I'm afraid all I can say is the relatively negative stuff from above :( You may well need to do formatting manually for things like ISO-week-year, as well as the computation. My Noda Time project (nodatime.org) may be useful for the computation, but I don't think we have format specifiers for week-year etc either.